# Making text smaller in one block in tikzposter

Tags: fontsize, tikzposter

I am trying to make an a1 academic poster in tikzposter and need to use 3 references, which I have put into a block using bibtex.

Is there a way to make the font in the block I have put references in smaller than in the other blocks? I have used size 20pt font, which I don't want to make any smaller for the content otherwise it will be hard to read but I'm running out of space and so could do with any extra I can get!

Here is the basic code I am using, I want to make the font size in the box called References smaller:

```
\documentclass[20pt,a1paper, landscape,colspace=0.7cm,blockverticalspace=1cm]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1.5cm}

\useblockstyle{Basic}

\usecolorstyle{Sweden}
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff

\title{\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{title}}
\author{author}
\institute{institution}

\begin{document}

% Introduction.
\maketitle

\begin{columns}

\column{0.7}
\block{Introduction}
{\begin{multicols}{2}
blah blah blah
\end{multicols}
}    

\begin{subcolumns}
\subcolumn{0.5}
\block{test}
{test
}

\subcolumn{0.5}
\block{test}
{testtest}

\end{subcolumns}

\column{0.3}
\block{}
{\vspace{-2cm}
\begin{tikzfigure}[caption]
\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{diagram.png}
\end{tikzfigure}
}


\block{References}
{\begingroup
\renewcommand\refname{\vskip -2cm}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
\bibliography{references}
\endgroup
}


\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Have you tried just adding `\small` or `\footnotesize` inside the desired block? AFAIK that should work.

Comment: Thanks very much, whatever I tried to put in clearly just wasn't doing anything!

Answer (score 4):

Putting `\small` at the beggining of the block works for me.

```
\block{References}
{
  \small
  \blindtext
}
```

[image]