# How to make the title larger in Tikz poster?

Tags: titles, fontsize, tikzposter

How does one increase the font size of the title of a poster using Tikz Poster?

Comment: Related:[Making text smaller in one block in tikzposter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230093/making-text-smaller-in-one-block-in-tikzposter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is not as straightforward as it seems at first sight. The title is printed with `\maketitle`, so it is a little bit more complicated to alter the fontsize of the title, than for the other blocks. To change the settings you can make use of the `\settitle` command. However, this seems to override all settings of the title block, which probably means you have to define the whole layout of this block yourself (see page 5 of the current manual for an example). As there is no indication in the manual, which font  sizes are predefined, and it seems as `\Huge` is the biggest you can get, you have to use the `\fontsize` command. However, I don't think this is a good solution, since Latex does provide predefined font sizes not without cause. Probably somebody with a little more experience in typesetting can tell something about this.

Anyway, here is a possible solution:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
%
\begin{document} 
    \title{Bla}
    \settitle{\centering{\bfseries \fontsize{100}{120} \sc \@title \par}}
    \maketitle
\end{document}
```

Setting `\fontsize{60}{72}` yields

[image]

while for `\fontsize{100}{120}` you'll get:

[image]

Comment: What is the difference of the two numbers, e.g., 100 and 120?